# How to tangle all the source code blocks inside a sub-tree using the properties drawer?

Tags: org-mode

I have a chapter heading in a literate program, in which all source-code is tangled into a single file called `test.hs`. It is irritating and error-prone to have to repeatedly type 
the `:tangle code/src/test.hs` for every new code block

Hence I would like to use the properties drawer of that chapter to once and for all tell Emacs to tangle ALL source code it sees inside this subtree to go into the file `test.hs`

My attempt at trying this did not work. How do I fix it?

```
 ** New Chapter
 :+PROPERTIES:
 :tangle: code/src/test.hs   (This does not work!)
 :END:

  #+BEGIN_SRC haskell
    import qualified Data.Map as Map  
    main = print "Hello World"
  #+END_SRC

  Here's the `add` function to add two numbers.     

  #+BEGIN_SRC haskell 
   add a b = a+b
  #+END_SRC
```

Comment: There is unnecessary +-sign in the example before PROPERTIES.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use :header-args: property instead. Like this

```
** New Chapter
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle code/src/test.hs
:END:
```

This behaviour changed with the Org-mode 9 (see [changes](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html#org343de47)). There is also entry on [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Header-arguments-in-Org-mode-properties.html).